# Qt localization

Tags: c++, qt

I have some problems with the localization of Qt programs.
At my computer all good but when i send my program to other users they can not see symbols of some languages. In this case I tested the Thai language.

Program output on screenshots:
My cpu OS: Windows 7 Ultimate x64 SP1
http://myprintscreen.com/s/1id

User cpu OS same: Windows 7 Ultimate x64 SP1
http://myprintscreen.com/s/1ie

User can print the Thai language in Microsoft Word and Notepad++ but not in the input fields of Qt.

And we found some interesting bug (http://myprintscreen.com/s/1if): If you copy the Thai text from a Microsoft Word in QTextEdit it displayed normally. QLineEdit and QPlainTextEdit do not display properly.

On Windows XP x86 SP3 (http://myprintscreen.com/s/1ii) does not display on Japanese but with Thai all is well :)

I try to use:

```
QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));
QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));
QTextCodec::setCodecForTr(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));
QString::fromUtf8
tr
trUtf8
QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8")->toUnicode
```

Qt project: http://www74.zippyshare.com/v/39453145/file.html

Help please. I can not understand what to do to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was simple. The problem with fonts on the user's computer. In my case Qt use by default MS Shell Dlg 2 font. But on user computer he was 'corrupted'. I added this code:

```
QApplication::setFont(QFontDialog::getFont(0, QApplication::font()));
```

and continue testing. Some fonts are displayed, and some do not. On different computers have different behavior.

That's why I decided to add to the distribution necessary for me font and install it for QApplication.